# css3 background-size weird

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a very weird problem with background-size: contain.

When I run my site from the local IIS of Visual Studio(F5) I can see the image shrinking according to its parent div.

But when I run the same site with the same css on an IIS that is on a server - I don't see it.

When I view the source code of the local site(F12 from IE) I can see background-size: contain;
but when I view the source code of the site that is on the server I don't see it.
When I open the css directly I do see it - Its the same code..:S

I run the sites from the same browser - Internet Explorer 9

Does css3 has anything to do with IIS Configurations??
Its very weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background-size: property isn't supported in IE7.  Please take a look at the compatibility chart:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#color

As an alternative to using the background-size property, please take a look at the following which may help:  http://bit.ly/JLbPCX

Comment: I meant IE 9. Sorry.
As I said it works once on a local IIS and doesn't work on the Servers IIS.
Both are run from the same IE 9 Browser

Comment: Oh ok in that case have you taken a look at the Document Mode your browser is using on your server?  You can check by hitting F12 to display the developer tools, if it isn't using Document Mode:  IE9 standards then that'll explain it.  There is a meta tag you can use to force a particular document mode which I recommend you use:  Please take a look here:  http://bit.ly/INPG4c